# Java Annotations and inheritance

Tags: java, serialization, nosql, pojo

I have a Person class which is used to hold data. I use this class in a library which does some logic. For example: calculates the person's birth year. **This library can also create new people.**

In another project, which uses the above library, I need to serialize the Person class into a database. I use a third party library for this. As is customary, I can put custom annotations on specific fields in order to serialize them.

So I have a bunch of Person instances. And I want to turn them into PersonAnonnatedDB instances . PersonAnonnatedDB extends Person, and adds no new methods or members. PersonAnonnatedDB does have added annotations to tell the DB how to serialize it, but nothing more.

Is there any way I can create PersonAnonnatedDB from Person without writing a long and trivial copy constructor?

I do not mind annotating Person with generic annotations. I just don't want to add Database specific annotations into my library project, as I might later work with other databases.

Basically, I want to decouple my data layer from my persistence layer, while writing minimal glue code.

Comment: i don't know if i followed that correctly, so this may be completely irrelevant to what you are trying to do, but look into the `super` keyword

Comment: I am not sure how super would help me here. You cannot automatically construct a class instance from it's superclass. Person is the superclass for PersonAnonnatedDB, so while i could easily construct a Person from a PersonAnonnatedDB I cannot do the opposite.

Comment: Ah I see what you want now.  yea, super won't help you.  sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use Hibernate with an [xml mapping document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html). This completely separates your code from the persistence setup, and removes the need to extend your Person object.

Comment: This looks useful, however one of the major DBs I am supporting is: Amazon DynamoDB which from a brief googling session, is not supported by hibernate.

Comment: Amazon DynamoDB is a NoSQL database. There is no way you would have similar code moving your data between your Java app and RDBMS and between your Java app and Amazon DynamoDB. So, leave your domain objects as-is, use Hibernate with XML mapping for interaction with a relational database and use some other code to work with DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to extend the class Person into PersonAnnotatedDB, where one member of the class is Person and one member is the annotation.
There would not be duplicate Person data, just a reference to an instance of Person.

Then it all depends on how you want to create, use or synchronize them with the the original Person.

Comment: In order to serialize a class properly, the annotations are specified on its' members and methods. Can I specify annotations for the inner Person class's fields while it is being held by an outer PersonAnnotatedDB?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you don't want to add annotations to Person, but only to PersonAnnotatedDB.

Comment: Yes. I want my logic code to remain oblivious to the fact that Person may be stored in a specific type of database. As such, Parson itself cannot include database specific annotations. I could achieve this trough an interface: IPerson, but then I cannot create new people in the algorithmic code. Basically, I want to decouple my data-model from my persistance layer.

Comment: Can this do what you want?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html#9.7
Here is an example of an annotation with a Class element whose value is restricted by the use of a bounded wildcard.
// Single-element annotation with Class element restricted by bounded wildcard
// The annotation presumes the existence of this class.
class GorgeousFormatter implements Formatter { ... }
@PrettyPrinter(GorgeousFormatter.class) public class Petunia {...}
// This annotation is illegal, as String is not a subtype of Formatter!!
@PrettyPrinter(String.class) public class Begonia { ... }

Comment: The annotations I am using are provided by the 3rd party database framework which I am using. I am not at liberty to change them.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritence: you absolutely cannot decorate the original class' fields with new annotations in a "class ? extends Person" (they are private, right? you even can't reference them).

Your decisions on where to put that class (some app, some of the libraries etc) were wrong. You have to move that class to the application and decorate properly for persistence.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed as much. I cannot put the annotated class in my core logic. I want to support at least two (or more) separate persistence solutions. If I decorate the model directly I will be forced to link both of my builds with each solution.

Comment: Then you are facing some kind of a hack. :/ Java is not designed for this situation.